# How to transmit lots of data(>4k) from ios to Multiple BLE devices Simultaneously

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

we need to implement a solution to transmit lots of data (>4k)to Multiple BLE devices(8 devices) Simultaneously and separately. Now the BLE packets losing is very serious, does anyone know how to deal with this problem and maximize the BLE data throughput.

Comment: Loss packet? Do do youse "write with response"?

Comment: "write with response" didn't lose packets, but too slow.